# What is the measurement of side KL in a scalene triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, unit-of-measure

**Given:** $\triangle FGH\cong \triangle JKL$

What is the measure of side 2 on triangle 2?

Here is what I have.

**Triangle 1:**

Side 1: Unknown

Side 2: Unknown

Side 3: 12

**Triangle 2:**

Side 1: Unknown

Side 2: y

Side 3 : 3y-15

Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have, since triangles are congruent

Side 3 (FGH) = Side 3 (JKL)

$3y-15=12$

Comment: Thanks! I cant believe I did not see that.